# c++ traits idiom in design

Tags: c++, oop, traits

consider definition

```
class A1{/*something*/};
```

two following options

> 1) using helper
>
> ```
> struct A1_helper{
> typedef A1 underlying; //let A1_helper user direct access to A1
> //whatever else necessary to work with A1...
> };
>
>
> template<typename A_helper>
> class B
> {
> //use A_helper
> }; 
>
>
> B<A1_helper> b;
> ```
>
> 2) using traits
>
> ```
> template<A>
> struct A_traits{
> //whatever necessary to work with A...
> };
>
>
>
> template<typename A>
> class B2
> {
>     //use A_traits<A>
> };
>
> B<A> b;
> ```

My question is: is there some essential difference between the two designs except the modernity of the traits? Is there something that can be done with one but not with the other? May be a better questions, when do you call something a trait?

Comment: I would say that both are traits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a significant difference in the meaning of the two approaches.

Approach 1 allows the user to customize how the handling of the type A is performed on a site by site basis.

```
struct A_helper_1 {
   static int to_int(A a) { return 1; }
};

struct A_helper_2 {
   static int to_int(A a) { return 2; }
};

A a;
B<A_helper_1> b1;
b1.printA(a);
B<A_helper_2> b2;
b2.printA(a);
```

With approach 2 there is only one true behaviour for a class A.

```
template<>
struct Helper<A> {
  static int to_int(A a) { return 1; }
};

A a;
B<A> b;
b.printA(a);
```

In approach 2 - if you want a new behavour you need to wrap your class

```
struct A2 : public A {/* ... all the constructors etc. ... */ }

template<>
struct Helper<A2> {
   static int to_int(A2 a) { return 1; }
}

B<A> b1;
B<A2> b2;
A a;
b1.printA(a);
// Only OK if you have a conversion operator in A2 - but will create a temp copy!
b2.printA(a); 
A2 a2;
b1.printA(a2); // OK but might copy a slice depending on call signature
b2.printA(a2);
```

So IMO using approach 1 suggests that the underlying code is extensible while approach 2 does not, since 1 is far easier to extend but a little more verbose in its instantiation ( `B<A_helper>` vs `B<A>`).

It is worth noting that you can get around some of the verboseness issue using approach 1, by doing the following additional steps, and using `C` instead of `B`.

```
template<typename T>
struct default_helper;

template<typename T>
using C = B<default_helper<T>>

template<>
struct default_helper<A> {
   static int to_int(A a) { return 1; }
}

A a;
C<A> c;
c.printA(a);
```